# Replacing true or false in table value with an image in Razor Pages

Tags: html, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Hi I am coding in Razor pages. I have a table where one of my values is boolean value where it shows either true or false in the table at the moment. I would like to switch these values with images in my wwwroot folder. The variable with a boolean value is the @tool.Borrowed.

My HTML Code

```
<table border ="1" class="table table-sortable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Verktøy Nummer</b></td>
            <th>Modell</th>
            <td><b>RFID nummer</b></td>
            <th>Kategori</th>
            <th>Utlånt</th>
            <td><b>Siste ansvarlige person</b></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var tool in Model.Tools) //Get the nessecary Tools from the tools Model from Tools.csgtml.cs
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@tool.ToolNumber</td>

            <td><a asp-page="/Tools/Details" asp-route-ID="@tool.ToolId">@tool.Model</a> </td>

            <td> @tool.ToolId </td>
            <td> @tool.Category</td>            
            <td> @tool.Borrowed</td>
            <td><a asp-page="/Employees/Details" asp-route-ID="@tool.EmployeeId">@tool.EmployeeName</a> </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add images depending on the value of  `@tool.Borrowed`.You can use [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator).Here is a demo:

wwwroot structure:

[image]

cshtml:

```
<table border="1" class="table table-sortable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Verktøy Nummer</b></td>
            <th>Modell</th>
            <td><b>RFID nummer</b></td>
            <th>Kategori</th>
            <th>Utlånt</th>
            <td><b>Siste ansvarlige person</b></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var tool in Model.Tools) //Get the nessecary Tools from the tools Model from Tools.csgtml.cs
        {
        <tr>
            <td>@tool.ToolNumber</td>

            <td><a asp-page="/Tools/Details" asp-route-ID="@tool.ToolId">@tool.Model</a> </td>

            <td> @tool.ToolId </td>
            <td> @tool.Category</td>
            <td><img src="@(tool.Borrowed?"/imgs/true.jpg":"/imgs/false.jpg")" /></td>
            <td><a asp-page="/Employees/Details" asp-route-ID="@tool.EmployeeId">@tool.EmployeeName</a> </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

cshtml.cs(I only test `@tool.Borrowed`):

```
 [BindProperty]
            public List<Tool> Tools { get; set; }
            public void OnGet()
            {
                Tools = new List<Tool> { new Tool { Borrowed = true }, new Tool { Borrowed = false }, new Tool { Borrowed = false } };
            }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Hi again, I do get an CS0266 Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?). In my Tool Model I have set the Borrowed value to be an nullable bool value. In cshtml.cs OnGet method I use a IEnumerable method as searchterm to get the context from my TOOL dbSet. Do you know how to fix this error?

Comment: I got it to work. I just had to change that my Tool class didn't have the borrowed value as an nullable bool. And insert False/True to my Database